# iOS create UIImage using a mask and a UIColor

Tags: ios, image, core-graphics

I'm currently coloring an existing image using a mask. For example, I have a white image with a black border and a circular mask (like the first two images). Then, I can create a third image with a color (i.e. green) which has green on the center of the original image (because the mask is present there).

[image]
[image]
[image]

The code I'm using is this (suggestions welcomed):

```
-(UIImage *)paintWithMask:(UIImage *)mask color:(UIColor *)color andSize:(CGSize)size{

    UIImage *image = self;
    UIImage *rotatedMask = [self rotateImage:mask]; //For some reason this is needed.

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, image.scale);

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width, size.height);
    [image drawInRect:rect];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeSourceIn);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, [rotatedMask CGImage]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIImage *coloredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return coloredImage;
}
```

What I need to do now is paint the green circle using **only** the mask (without the black border obviously), like this:

[image]
[image]

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Comment out the line `[image drawInRect:rect]` ?

Comment: It doesn't work. Nothing appears.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much easier way of doing this without CoreGraphics. Simply do the following:

```
-(UIImageView *)imageViewWithMask:(UIImage *)mask color:(UIColor *)color andSize:(CGSize)size{
    UIImage *tempImage = mask;
    tempImage = [tempImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO,0);
    [tempImage drawInRect: CGRectMake(0,0,size.width,size.height)];
    tempImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: tempImage];
    iv.tintColor = color;
    return iv;
}
```

Comment: contentMode is a property of UIView, not UIImage. How would you  change this to make it work? Maybe as a category of UIImageView?

Comment: Sorry! I didn't have Xcode open to check it. I'll correct the snippet.

Comment: Turns out CoreGraphics is necessary. My old scale method works if used on a UIImageView.

Comment: I could make it work with a UIImageView.. Your code has some errors, I guess it's because you figured out it wouldn't work? How would you change it to make it work on a UIImageView? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, just use the imageView returned by the new func.